# How to find out if "navbar-toggle" button is collapsed or hidden with Javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, button

Is there a way to find out, with JS, if the toggle button menu is collapsed or hidden.

Does **class="navbar-toggle"** **or data-toggle="collapse"** have a parameter which indicates this state?

I know the events that are called when the ".collape" is shown or hidden:

`$('.navbar-collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
//called when dropdown menu is shown
});`

Furthermore, I know the methods that shows or hides the collapse like this:

```
$('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
```

But I can´t find any information on how to get the current status of .collapse, telling me if it´s hidden or shown.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The answer is yes but please rephere the SO rules to see how to add a question. There are multiple issues with your questions, starting with the fact that a simple google over that text would bring up the answer, to the fact that you refere some non-standard class (although you probably use bootstrap).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(I am editing this answer with a better way.)

Yes, you can check if the element is visible, using jquery $(element).is(":visible")

Here is a [live demo on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nikki9696/endwbLco/)

Here is some html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="clickedIt()" />
```

Here is some javascript

```
function clickedIt() {   
   var canSee = $("#myNavbar").is(":visible");
   alert(canSee);
}
```

Comment: I see, but how exactly can I retrieve the status of the .collapse with this hasClass?
By looking around in the web, the only thing I found were the events for hidding and showing.

Comment: Just use the property to check it whenever you wanted it. e.g. if ($("#selector").hasClass("collapsed")

Comment: After experimenting on jsFiddle, I decided that wasn't the right way to go about it. I have edited the answer to check visible property.

Comment: I see, this is the way it works. Thanks for the great help, I really appreciate it. Unfortunately I cant upvote your post, I gotta earn 15 reputation first. Anyway Thank you for your effort to help me out.

Comment: To detect when the dropdown menu is expanded AND the screen is narrow, checking for is(':visible') is not enough, I ended up checking for $('#selector').position().top>$('.navbar').position().top additionally.